# How can i set the path for the trace file in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, trace

I have an application in C#. After building and executing my exe the application somtimes writes a appname.trc file in my application folder. Can i define the path of this file and why is this file created on errors like file access?

Comment: Are you sure this file is not created by your app through code?

Comment: I know my code and dont create a file called appname.trc

Comment: I don't think so, because my app writes fatal errors like access denied or else in this file. It is not the first time that applications created with vs2010 automatically writes such file.

Comment: @CubaLibre: What is content of this file? Is this some trace information ?

Comment: Is your app dealing with Oracle? `TRC is an Oracle Trace file. TRC files are designed to provide more information about errors that are detected and reported by Oracle database software.`

Comment: The content is some trace infos and the app does not deal with any oracle stuff.

Comment: But does it deal with some tracers? Have a look on tracers you use

Comment: I dont know what you mean but is it not possible to set the path in VS2010?